# css styling table borders looking strange

Tags: html, css

I encountered strange problem with table styling. Everything at least for me in code seems to be fine. however effects are unexpected.

I have to leave 0.3em margin as this is my student task, but I don't want the lines in the bottom to be separate.

Any webmaster can help? I would be very thankful. Here is peace of my code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Kategoriasystematyczna</td>
<td>Takson</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Domena</td>
<td>eukarionty</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Królestwo</td>
<td>zwierzęta</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gromada</td>
<td>ssaki</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Podgromada</td>
<td>ssakiżyworodne
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Infragromada</td>
<td>łożyskowce
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rząd</td>
<td>parzystokopytne
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rodzina</td>
<td>żyrafowate
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Rodzaj</td>
<td>Giraffa(Brünnich,1771)
<td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Gatunek</td>
<td>żyrafa
<td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and style

```
td{
border:1pxsolidblue;
margin:0.3em,0.3em,0.3em,0.3em;
}
table{
border:1pxsolidblue;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

And this is how my table looks like

[image: table]

Anyone? Antyhing?

Answer (score 1):

you have opening tags instead of closing tags td:

change

```
<td>Gatunek</td>
<td>żyrafa
<td>
```

to

```
<td>Gatunek</td>
<td>żyrafa
</td>
```

in various places

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my original comment to your answer (prior to deletion for redundancy), the problem is the syntax errors of unclosed `<td>` elements (possibly typos), correcting your HTML fixes the problem. Corrected HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Kategoriasystematyczna</td>
        <td>Takson</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Domena</td>
        <td>eukarionty</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Królestwo</td>
        <td>zwierzęta</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gromada</td>
        <td>ssaki</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Podgromada</td>
        <td>ssakiżyworodne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Infragromada</td>
        <td>łożyskowce</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rząd</td>
        <td>parzystokopytne</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rodzina</td>
        <td>żyrafowate</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rodzaj</td>
        <td>Giraffa(Brünnich,1771)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gatunek</td>
        <td>żyrafa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/A8357/1/).

Also, your CSS is problematic, you have commas between the values of your `margin` property-values and no spaces to separate the properties of the border; fixed, it should look like:

```
td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    margin: 0.3em;
}
table {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```